# Odata: The query parameter '$count' is not supported

Tags: json, kendo-ui, odata

Server: Odata controllers generated with standard VS 2015 generator.

```
// GET: odata/MyEntities
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
public IQueryable<Models.Odata. MyEntity> GetMyEntities()
{
  return db.MyEntities;
}
```

Client: KendoUI

```
var ds = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  type: "odata-v4",
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "odata/EndPoints",
      dataType: "json"
    }
  },
  schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
            }
        }
  });
```

Request:

`http://localhost:44444/odata/MyEntities?$format=json` - returns whats expected, 
but

`http://localhost:44444/odata/MyEntities?$format=json&$count=true` - produces error:

```
{
  "odata.error":{
    "code":"","message":{
      "lang":"en-US","value":"The query parameter '$count' is not supported."
    }
  }
}
```

I used standard settings in AppStart. What is it?

Comment: Why the =true ? http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#count

Comment: $count without true produces the same result

Comment: What data service version is it passing? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg312156.aspx#DetermineDataServiceVersion

Comment: DataServiceVersion 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OData version 3 has a query option named `$inlinecount`, not `$count`. It appears you are confusing the query option with both the `/$count` path segment, and the `$count` query option from version *4*.

Request the total count of entities in a collection, along with the entities themselves:

```
GET http://localhost:44444/odata/MyEntities?$format=json&$inlinecount=allpages
```

Request only the count of an entity collection:

```
GET http://localhost:44444/odata/MyEntities/$count?$format=json
```

See [OData Version 3.0 Core Protocol](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/), sections 10.2.3.6 and 10.2.5.

Comment: Regenerated controllers with Odatav4 generator, reinstalled packages, checked version = 4, and it works.Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! It's good that you were able to upgrade to v4. BTW, JSON is the default wire format in v4, so you no longer need the `$format=json` query option.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Microsoft.AspNet.OData namespace instead of System.Web.Http.OData in your controller.